# Why do anonymous functions appear to be rejected inside this PHP Object

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I am currently just messing around with PHP and I noticed something interesting that I personally haven't noticed. Anonymous functions do not seem to work inside objects. Why?

Example:

```
$loop = function ($do) {
    $i = 2;
    $do((object) [
        "i" => $i,
        "domore" => (function () {
            echo "hi";
        })
    ]);
};

$loop(function ($data) {
   echo $data->i;
   echo $data->domore();
});
```

**Throws Error:**

```
2<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::delay() in [...][...]:16
Stack trace:
#0 [...][...](10): {closure}(Object(stdClass))
#1 [...][...](17): {closure}(Object(Closure))
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

Likewise the same code with the return data being an array instead of an object:

```
$loop = function ($do) {
    $i = 2;
    $do([
        "i" => $i,
        "domore" => function () {
            echo "hi";
        }
    ]);
};

$loop(function ($data) {
   echo $data["i"];
   echo $data["domore"]();
});
```

Simply returns, `2hi`, as expected. This seems like strange behavior to me (someone coming from javascript) so I would appreciate some sort of justification. Note that this code serves no real life purpose so good or bad practice has no influence here. Think educational.

***Edit:* Laravel does exactly what I want giving me the notion that it is not impossible but I simply implemented it incorrectly in PHP:**

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', function ($join) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')->orOn(...);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous functions work fine in objects. You're getting that error because `domore` isn't a method and you're calling it as such, it's a property that happens to be a closure. To distinguish you'll need to use parentheses when addressing the property, e.g.:

```
$loop(function ($data) {
   echo $data->i;
   echo ($data->domore)();
});
```

Outputs:

```
2hi
```

---

Why this is necessary is because methods and properties live in different symbol tables, meaning you can have a property and a method of the same name *(please don't do this)* and you need to know which is being addressed. E.g.:

```
$foo = new class
{
    public $func;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->func = function () {
            echo "foo";
        };
    }

    public function func()
    {
        echo "bar";
    }
};

($foo->func)();
$foo->func();
```

Outputs:

```
foobar
```

Comment: So how does laravel accomplish the more clean look?

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'` -> `echo ($data->domore)();`

Comment: Ah yes. Was testing in 5.6

Comment: @Shawn31313 The laravel snippet you gave doesn't give enough info to explain what they're doing, and I really have no interest in digging through that framework.

Comment: @PaulCrovella No problem, maybe someone else can explain

Comment: @Shawn31313 First guess without looking, and without knowing what `$join->on` actually is in your example, is they could be doing some magic `__call` nonsense like `public function __call($name, $arguments) { return ($this->$name)(...$arguments);}`